# Oracle 12c search and replace

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle12c

I'm developing a tool using oracle 12c. I need to do search and replace. For example I have a string "Z_MEMBER_MONTHS and Z_MEMBER" . I want to replace "Z_MEMBER_MONTHS" to "Z_MEMBER_MONTHS_QA" and "Z_member" to Z_member_qa". How to achieve it?

when I use regex_replace it is doing like search and replacing is not happening properly. I'm jus looking for exact search replace instead of like search. please help.

Comment: If you explain what you are trying to properly in the question, with examples, you won't get repeated answers that aren't helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

LMGTFY The function you are looking for is REPLACE.

Learn more about it here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm

```
SELECT REPLACE('Z_MEMBER_MONTHS','MONTHS','MONTHS_QA') FROM DUAL
```